# Using Google Tag Manager to prevent logged in Wordpress users cluttering my Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager on https://therichtimes.com and want the GA tags to not fire if user is logged into Wordpress on the same blog.

I have done the following:

1) Installed below code into the 'head' ABOVE the Google Tag Manager code.

2) Verified that when I am logged-in , this appears in my code(when done view source) - dataLayer.push({'visitorLoginState': 'logged-in'})

3) Verified that if I am not logged in or using incognito mode, then following is in my code - dataLayer.push({'visitorLoginState': 'logged-out'})

4) Set up the GTM trigger for event type 'page view' to load on some page views only, when visitorLoginState contains logged-in.

5) Added this trigger as an exception to the GA firing trigger i.e. GA tags to fire on all page views EXCEPT when visitorLoginState is logged-in.

6) Problem is, when I preview via GTM and visit my blog, even when logged-in, the GA tags still fire. I have identified the issue down to the the data layer variable being 'not defined' on page load. I would expect to see the value that is either logged-in or logged-out ; but clearly this isn't getting done.  Is the datalayer push not working? Is my code wrong or is it the setup?

```
<!-- exclude WP logged in -->
<script>
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo "dataLayer.push({'visitorLoginState': 'logged-in'});";
} else {
echo "dataLayer.push({'visitorLoginState': 'logged-out'});";
}
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically gives it away - you try to add data to an array that does not yet exist. Initialize the datalayer before you push data to it:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
<!-- exclude WP logged in -->
<script>
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo "dataLayer.push({'visitorLoginState': 'logged-in'});";
} else {
echo "dataLayer.push({'visitorLoginState': 'logged-out'});";
}
?>
</script>
```

The top line says, "if there is a global datalayer variable use that, else declare a new array with that name".

You also need a new event (i.e. a key/value pair where the key is "event") with, or following a push on the datalayer, else GTM will not update its variables internally. However since your script is above the GTM script the built-in standard events will take care of that (but remember this if you add data after the page has loaded).

[The indispensable Simo Ahava has more details](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/datalayer-declaration-vs-push/).